# Smoke Simulation Not Showing in Camera

Tags: rendering, particles, camera, smoke-simulation

So I was trying to create a smoke simulation and it shows up fine in the rendered view but as soon as I go to the camera, It disappears.

In the picture, the two sides are the same view and angle but the right is in the camera and the left is not.

Here's the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx4pBUqoLAb-UnVLT0dTTEJlcU0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply for I have been working all day on this. I haven't used the Smoke/Flame physics at all so an extensive amount of experimenting showed that all you have to do is select the Smoke Domain cube and, under Smoke cache, click `Bake`:
[image: Click Bake]

After this your viewport should look something like this:
[image: Final Smoke]

Then you should be able to see the smoke through the camera and in the final render.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for the super late reply to your late reply but I finally got around to trying this and it works so thanks!

Comment: Don't mention it

Answer (score 1):

This is because left side is rendered mode and right is solid mode. Blender doesn't show smoke and/or fire at full quality in solid mode in the viewport instead it shows only a little bit. If you see closely, in the file you provided, you can see a small white cloud of smoke, but in rendered mode it turns into a dense black mass of smoke.

Comment: if you go into the camera in rendered mode though, does the dense black mass disappear because it does for me

Comment: I see what you mean. It doesn't show up in the final render either